# Exit signal not being caught in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Writing a script to render arbitrary HTML as an image, and using PyQt. I'm confused as to why my `QApplication.exit` call isn't making `QApplication.exec_` return. Any ideas on this?

```
class ScreenshotterApplication(QApplication):

    def __init__(self, args, html):
        QApplication.__init__(self, args)

        self.html = html

        self.browser = QWebView()
        self.browser.resize(0, 0)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.save)
        self.browser.loadProgress.connect(self.progress)

    def render(self):
        self.browser.setHtml(self.html)

    def progress(self, progress):
        print '%d%%' % progress

    def save(self, finished):
        success = False
        if finished:
            print 'saving...'
            # ... snip ...

            success = pixmap.save('screenshot.png')
            if success:
                print 'saved as "screenshot.png"'

        QApplication.exit(0 if success else 1)

    def exec_(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.render()
        super(QApplication, self).exec_(*args, **kwargs)

def take_screenshot(html):
    app = ScreenshotterApplication(sys.argv, html)
    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print take_screenshot('<h1 style="width: 500px">Hello, World!</h1>')
```

Comment: Oh, and it's worked before. I'm not sure if I changed something but no matter what I do now, it won't exit correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`QApplication.exit`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#exit) tells the application to leave the main event loop, i.e. to return from `exec_()` as soon as possible.

Your problem is that the small piece of static HTML is so easy to retrieve and render, QtWebKit does it right when setHtml is called. No delays or background processing, everything's done before setHtml returns. So, `save` is called *before* the main loop starts (i.e. before `exec_` is called).

It's like writing `return` when you're not in a function – except Qt will just ignore `exit` quietly if the loop isn't running.

Solution: Use a [`QueuedConnection`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) in your `connect` call to force the signal to be queued, and delivered when event loop starts. This'll also work if the loop *is* already running, of course.

```
self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.save, Qt.QueuedConnection)
```